# Tracking memory consumption in python script during execution

Tags: python, memory-management

I have a large amount of data obtained earlier (> 500 GByte), and would like to process it using Python (or other languages, if necessary). I can not load all data into memory at once (due to obvious reasons), and therefore can only load small chunks. I already tried optimizing the memory consumption as much as possible, by explicitly clearing all generated lists and arrays between each chunk, but I still can see the memory consumption increasing steadily.
Are there ways to track at which point I am not freeing memory, and at which point my memory accumulates? What would be the best strategy here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with python3.4, you can use the tracemalloc module.